# form filter instead of form

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

i generated new project in Symfony with very simple schema:

```
News:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    title:              { type: string(255) }
    is_active:          { type: string(1) }
```

In action.class.php in

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
```

i added:

```
$this->filter = new NewsFormFilter();
```

and in NewSuccess.php

```
echo $filter;
```

now i have form filter, but there aren't data and execute submit. Only clean form. 
what i have to do that there were data News and work this same as in backhand Jobeet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class form generates only field widget. You have to add form tags and submit tag by yourself in template layer.

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('contact/submit') ?>" method="POST">
 <table>
  <?php echo $form ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input type="submit" />
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, but i poorly know Symfony. How can i it make? is generator for this?

Comment: this is a good link to learn basics of form creation : http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/01-Form-Creation

Comment: and where are data from News? this is only form

Answer (score 2):

You can analyze code generated by symfony's Admin Generator to find out how it works. Generate admin module for your News model by command:

```
$ symfony doctrine:generate-admin backend News
```

Open backend in your browser to let symfony generate the cache and then see generated files in folder `/cache/backend/modules/autoNews/` (actions and templates).

You may also read the [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/12) about Admin Generator.